# Dynamic Gesture Recognition and Kinect with Python?

Tags: python, gesture-recognition, kinect-v2, pykinect

I am working on "Kinect for XBox One" on my HP Laptop with Windows 10 and 64-bit operating system. I have worked on python before and want to work in it only with jupyter notebok or python command line. 
The topic of my project is Dynamic Sign Language Recognition and till now I have worked on only static images. I found many tutorials for working with kinect camera but every tutorial has been done with C++, C# or Sketch in Processing 3. I have downloaded Processing 3 and tried some programs in Sketch also by following this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKatPT3HlqA
But even after 2 days, I am not able to run a simple program in it and only a black picture is there as an output, kinect is detected though.

I have also tried Pykinect and python example from this link: https://github.com/Kinect/PyKinect2

It was good and I was able to track the skeleton of the body. I want to learn Pykinect and many more such examples but I am not getting any source from where I can learn all these. My aim is to use all the three cues:RGB, Depth, and Skeleton for my work.

Even for dynamic gesture recognition, there are projects in C++ and languages other than python.

If you have any suggestions regarding kinect with python and dynamic gesture recognition, then you are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for days, I figured out that there are no tutorials on Kinect using Python. Those who want to learn kinect with python and Windows should go to this link first:  https://github.com/Kinect/PyKinect2
Go by the instructions and run the example programs whether in Visual studio, python command line or jupyter notebook. There are no tutorials defining the programming functions of Pykinect library. The only way to learn it is through one more link:
https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS
Explore this link as it has one or two more examples which will help in understanding the functions. I am not done yet so I will keep updating my answer if I find any more sources.